# How to create a custom hook that recives dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, react-hooks

I'm making a custom hook that have a toogle when some state change.

You should be able to pass any state in an array.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useFlatListUpdate = (dependencies = []) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setToggle(t => !t)
    }, [...dependencies])

    return toggle
}

export default useFlatListUpdate
```

And it should be used as

```
const toggleFlatList = useFlatListUpdate([search, selectedField /*, anything */])
```

But it gives me the following warning

> React Hook useEffect has a spread element in its dependency array. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

I also have another situation where it doesn't work

```
const useFlatListUpdate = (dependencies = []) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setToggle(t => !t)
    }, dependencies)

    return toggle
}
```

This gives me the warning

> React Hook useEffect was passed a dependency list that is not an array literal. This means we can't statically verify whether you've passed the correct dependencies.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

How can I make this work without the warning and without disabling eslint?

Comment: You are right. My answer is dead-wrong. I deleted it not to confuse you and others further. I apologize 

Comment: @dance2die Your answer wasn't wrong, but it just gave another type of warning.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I wasn't able to get it working with refs either so I will leave this matter to others :)

Comment: for your second example just put dependencies inside an array: `useEffect(() => {
        setToggle(t => !t)
    }, [dependencies])`

Answer (score 7):

Use of dependency list is very peculiar in this case.
I do not see other way except ignoring or silencing the warning.

To silence the warning, we do not have to  disable `eslint` completely.
You can disable this specific rule for this specific line:

```
const useFlatListUpdate = (dependencies = []) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
    useEffect(() => {
        setToggle(t => !t)
    }, [...dependencies])

    return toggle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to create a custom hook as per the question.

You can use `useEffect` to check whether your dependency has changed or not if it is changed set the toggle something like this in your component.

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
useEffect(() =>{
  setToggle(!toggle);
}, [yourDepndency]);
```

**Help me to understand if I have understood your requirement correctly.**

Answer (score 0):

In the first situation, you are asked to avoid array spreading,
So you should just pass the dependancyList as a whole :

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setToggle(t => !t)
    }, dependencies)
```

The next warning says that you miss a dependancy (`setToggle`).

You can use a `useCallback` with the inner effect dependancies, and then wrap it in the useEffect with the hook-user provided dependancies:

```js
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useFlatListUpdate = (dependencies = []) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

    useCallback(() => { setToggle(t => !t) }, [setToggle])
    useEffect(toggleEffect, dependencies])

    return toggle
}

export default useFlatListUpdate
```

Comment: setToggle does not require being wrapped in a useCallback

Answer (score 0):

just keep my record here, sometime i'll forget too

```
const useCustomHook = (props, deps) => {
    const value = useMemo(()=> props.value, deps)
    return {value}
}
```